# What is an eMac?

Tags: discussion

I honestly didn't know what a Emac is.  It seems that this would be a good thing to have on a site like [Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMac):

> The eMac, short for education Mac, is a Macintosh desktop computer made by Apple Inc. It was originally aimed at the education market, but was later made available as a cheaper mass market alternative to Apple's second-generation LCD display iMac G4. The eMac was pulled from retail on October 12, 2005 and was sold exclusively to educational institutions thereafter. It was discontinued by Apple on July 5, 2006 and replaced by a cheaper, low-end iMac that, like the eMac, was originally sold exclusively to educational institutions.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs):

> Emacs /ˈiːmæks/ and its derivatives are a family of text editors that are characterized by their extensibility. The manual for the most widely used variant, GNU Emacs, describes it as "the extensible, customizable, self-documenting, real-time display editor".[1] Development of the first Emacs began in the mid-1970s and continues actively as of 2014. Emacs has over 2,000 built-in commands and allows the user to combine these commands into macros to automate work. Emacs Lisp provides a deep extension capability allowing users and developers to write new commands using a variant of the Lisp programming language.

Even on Wikipedia, there are conflicting definitions - which one is this site about?

Comment: I'm afraid even that list [isn't entirely comprehensive](http://www.chicagobusiness.com/article/20001204/NEWS/20001021/mcdonalds-to-serve-emac).

Comment: Indeed - that wasn't my point.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com for the first and this site for the second.

Comment: When I first read this I thought it was a joke. I now realize that it's not. But if it were, it would be genius.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second one.

Let this be a lesson: we must update https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tour and other mostly stock pages.

Comment: Do we have a second.

Comment: @cullub The editor. This site is about the editor.

Comment: re `/tour`: is there a means by which we can help update these pages?  This is the first Beta site I've really participated in, so the ins-and-outs are still new to me.

Comment: @SeanAllred Only Stack Exchange staff can update the “is a question and answer site for” part. And while they're at it they should fix the double “for”.

Comment: "Emacs Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those using, extending or developing emacs text editors" okay with you lot?

Comment: Or: "Emacs Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those using, extending or developing the emacs text editor" ?

Comment: Sure. Tour page is updated.

Answer (score 4):

This site is about **[Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)**, not about **eMacs**. (A site about an obsolete and piece of hardware that never had a major cult following would be rather improbable anyway.)

Which is not to say that the site description couldn't stand a bit of clarification — make it “the Emacs editor” instead of “emacs”.

(And yes, Emacs is [officially](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) an editor. One in which you can do a lot of things other than editing files, but still an editor.)